# Why is my code returning the same prompt twice?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

```
MinimumGrade = 0
MaximumGrade = int(4.3)

F = 0
D = 0.85
D_Plus = 1.15
C_Minus = 1.5
C = 1.85
C_Plus = 2.15
B_Minus = 2.5
B = 2.85
B_Plus = 3.15
A_Minus = 3.5
A = 3.85
A_Plus = 4.06

GPA = round(float(input('Enter Term GPA (0-4.3):')), 1)

def LetterGrade():
    if GPA <= D:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "F"))
    elif GPA < D_Plus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "D"))
    elif GPA < C_Minus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "D+"))
    elif GPA < C:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "C-"))
    elif GPA < C_Plus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "C"))
    elif GPA < B_Minus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "C+"))
    elif GPA < B:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "B-"))
    elif GPA < B_Plus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "B"))
    elif GPA < A_Minus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "B+"))
    elif GPA < A:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "A-"))
    elif GPA < A_Plus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "A"))
    elif GPA >= A_Plus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "A+"))


done = False
while done == False:
    GPA = round(float(input('Enter Term GPA (0-4.3):')), 1)
    if GPA < MinimumGrade or GPA > MaximumGrade:
        continue
    else:
        print("%s %0.1f" %("Term GPA:", GPA))
        LetterGrade()
        done = True
```

So, I'm trying to get the if statement to return the prompt only once when the user enters a valid number, issue is, it keeps asking twice even if the number is in range. I've tried fiddling with the makeup of the if statement, but everything keeps breaking. Is there a specific place that's made wrong?

Comment: you ask once outside the loop ... and then it always goes into the loop where it asks at least once ...

Comment: Do you mean the input? Well, you ask for it twice. There are two lines with `GPA = round(float(input('Enter Term GPA (0-4.3):')), 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you placed the statement `GPA = round(float(input('Enter Term GPA (0-4.3):')), 1)` twice. Before and inside your while loop.

Also, you should use a while True statement instead like this. The code below should run properly.

```
MinimumGrade = 0
MaximumGrade = int(4.3)

F = 0
D = 0.85
D_Plus = 1.15
C_Minus = 1.5
C = 1.85
C_Plus = 2.15
B_Minus = 2.5
B = 2.85
B_Plus = 3.15
A_Minus = 3.5
A = 3.85
A_Plus = 4.06

def LetterGrade():
    if GPA <= D:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "F"))
    elif GPA < D_Plus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "D"))
    elif GPA < C_Minus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "D+"))
    elif GPA < C:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "C-"))
    elif GPA < C_Plus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "C"))
    elif GPA < B_Minus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "C+"))
    elif GPA < B:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "B-"))
    elif GPA < B_Plus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "B"))
    elif GPA < A_Minus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "B+"))
    elif GPA < A:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "A-"))
    elif GPA < A_Plus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "A"))
    elif GPA >= A_Plus:
        print("\t %s %s" % ("Letter Grade:", "A+"))


while True:
    GPA = round(float(input('Enter Term GPA (0-4.3):')), 1)
    if GPA < MinimumGrade or GPA > MaximumGrade:
        continue
    else:
        print("%s %0.1f" %("Term GPA:", GPA))
        LetterGrade()
        break
```